# RxJava2 - Mutlicasting Singles, Maybes, and Completables?

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

What is the recommend way to multicast Singles, Maybes, and Completables? Is it just recommended to turn them into standard Observables to multicast them?

```
    Observable<String> strings =
            Observable.just("Alpha", "Beta", "Gamma", "Delta", "Epsilon");

    Observable<Integer> lengths = strings.map(String::length);

    ConnectableObservable<List<Integer>> lengthsList = 
            lengths.toList().toObservable().publish();
```

I'm a bit surprised there is no `ConnectableSingle`, `ConnectableMaybe`, and `ConnectableCompletable`. What is the reasoning behind this? Is it just not worth the effort to develop?

Comment: Each has a `cache()` operator and 2.0.5 will have a `Subject` variant. There was no need for connectable versions and I don't feel they are necessary at all. Since you can walk between the types, you can workaround this as you showed.

Comment: @akarnokd cache() doesn't allow dispose upstream source. The upstream keeps subscribed even all receivers are disposed, but sometime we need to share a source only while any receivers are subscribed to it.

Answer (score 0):

I think, `.toObservable().publish()` is the way to go.